# python - How to avoid multiple running instances of the same function

Tags: python, function

In my python script I have a `core dumped`, and I think it's because the same function is called twice at the same time.

The function is the reading of a Vte terminal in a gtk window

```
def term(self, dPluzz, donnees=None):
    text = str(self.v.get_text(lambda *a: True).rstrip())
    [...]
    print "Here is the time " + str(time.time())

def terminal(self):    
    self.v = vte.Terminal()
    self.v.set_emulation('xterm')
    self.v.connect ("child-exited", lambda term: self.verif(self, dPluzz))
    self.v.connect("contents-changed", self.term)
```

Result:

```
Here is the time 1474816913.68
Here is the time 1474816913.68
Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)
```

How to avoid the double executing of the function?

Comment: To my knowledge the only possible way to "double execute" a code section is using threading. But Python has Global Interpreter Lock, so even then it is not really "double execute". Normally speaking one would add locks to critical sections so that threads are queued up before entering the sections. https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#lock-objects

Comment: Thanks. How about the double print? Weird? This is the first time I see it. The script works well in Ubuntu but this bug appear in OpenSuse...

Comment: Where's a bug?  the function is called very time contents is changed. So you have to look into the documentation, what this really means.

Comment: A [mcve] would be welcome here mon gars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double execution must be the consequence of the `contents-changed` event triggering twice.

You could just check in your `term` function whether it has already been executed before, and exit if so.

Add these two lines at the start of the `term` function:

```
    if hasattr(self, 'term_has_executed'): return
    self.term_has_executed = True
```

Comment: Thanks, but with these lines the function is not executed at all.
Said that the core dumped has disappeared

Answer (score 1):

I created a python decorator (mutli-platform compatible) which provide a mecanism to avoid concurrent execution.
The usage is :

```
@lock('file.lock')
def run():
    # Function action
    pass
```

Personnaly, I am used to using relative path :

```
CURRENT_FILE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
@lock(os.path.join(CURRENT_FILE_DIR, os.path.basename(__file__)+".lock"))
```

The decorator :

```
import os

def lock(lock_file):
    """
    Usage:
        @lock('file.lock')
        def run():
            # Function action
    """
    def decorator(target):

        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

            if os.path.exists(lock_file):
                raise Exception('Unable to get exclusive lock.')
            else:
                with open(lock_file, "w") as f:
                    f.write("LOCK")

            # Execute the target
            result = target(*args, **kwargs)

            remove_attempts = 10
            os.remove(lock_file)
            while os.path.exists(lock_file) and remove_attempts >= 1:

                os.remove(lock_file)
                remove_attempts-=1

            return result
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

### For mutlithread calls

There is a unix solution for manage multithread calls : https://gist.github.com/mvliet/5715690

Don't forget to thank the author of this gist (it's not me).

Comment: nice idea. haven't tried it yet, but it looks promising.